# How can I count the same values ​in the array and create a different array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

```
[{
    "project_name": "test",
    "status": "High"
},{
    "project_name": "test",
    "status": "Critical"
},{
    "project_name": "test",
    "status": "Critical"
}]
```

I tried a lot with Object.entries, but I couldn't reach the result I wanted.

***Expected Output***

```
[{
  project_name: "test",
  value: 1,
  status: "High",
},
{
  project_name: "test",
  value: 2,
  status: "Critical",
}]
```

What I want to do is not add a value, but consider more objects in the first array with the same status values. I want to count and group them all.

Comment: What did you try with Object.entries? What result did that produce? It appears that you simply want to add a value attribute to your objects...

Comment: @TahaYıldırım You could use `array.map` and add the property on each object [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Why not just loop through the array and add the value to each object?

Comment: What does the `value` pertain to? It just seems you're adding a new property for <a reason> which you've not described in your question.

Comment: I think I explained the question poorly. I edited. what i want is to group statuses with same values

Comment: Can you tell something by looking at the new edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a temporary object to hold the updated information.
2. Loop over the array, and for each object create a bespoke key from the `product_name` and the `status`.
3. If the key doesn't exist on the temporary object create a new object from the current one, and add a value property.
4. Increase the value by one.
5. Finally you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get at the new objects from the temporary array.

```js
const data=[{project_name:"test",status:"High"},{project_name:"test",status:"Critical"},{project_name:"test",status:"Critical"}];

const temp = {};

for (const obj of data) {
  const { project_name, status } = obj;
  const key = `${project_name}-${status}`;
  temp[key] ??= { ...obj, value: 0 };
  temp[key].value += 1;
}

console.log(Object.values(temp));
```

Additional documentation

- [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

---

You can also use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). The same principles apply (but here you're just initialising an empty object for the accumulator, and passing that through to the next iteration of the array) though the loop might be simpler to understand if you're new to JS.

```js
const data=[{project_name:"test",status:"High"},{project_name:"test",status:"Critical"},{project_name:"test",status:"Critical"}];

const out = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const { project_name, status } = obj;
  const key = `${project_name}-${status}`;
  acc[key] ??= { ...obj, value: 0 };
  acc[key].value += 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(out));
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for explaining it so well. It has really been very useful for me. Thank you.